# Passing the image attribute of a model in a function in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, web, django-models, face-recognition

I have a function called `detectFace(input_file)`, where the input file is an Image. I want to render the results via `views.py` on a template but could not find a way to do it. The image will be uploaded via the template and will run on the `detectFace(input_file)`.

something like this:-

```
def detectFace(input_file):
    """Operation on input_file
    """
    pass
```

Now in `views.py` I am trying to creating something like this

```
def face_recog(request):
    context = ??
    return render(request, 'templates/face.html', context)
```

I want to know those question marks. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the uploaded file by accessing `request.FILES['filename']` and then you can pass that file to your function. Something like:

```
def detectFace(input_file):
    """Operation on input_file
    """
    # Some processing
    return something

def face_recog(request):
    input_file = request.FILES['image_file']
    some_data = detectFace(input_file) # call the function
    context = {'somekey': some_data} # data returned by detectFace() function.
    return render(request, 'templates/face.html', context)
```

And in your HTML the form should look something like this:

```
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="image_file" />
    <input type="submit"></input>
    {{ form }}
</form>
```